# Writing to a SQL Server table using powerapps

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerapps

I'm trying to write to a SQL Server table `[frm].[Resultran]`.

It has a `Resultid` column which is the primary key and it's set as an `autonumber`.

Currently on a button on the on select property I have the following code:

```
Patch('[frm].[Resultran], Default('[frm].[Resultran]'),{Creationdate: now(), Result: Radio1.selected} )
```

I have looked at some websites to see if my syntax is correct and I found that I have put it correctly . Unfortunately its coming up with an error stating:

> Patch has some invalid arguments

Can someone assist me please?

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is Default**s**(datasource). You're missing the "s" in your formula.